# Esky update causes transacted file operations error

Tags: python, windows

Here is the error I get when I run esky auto_update:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "__main__.py", line 838, in <module>
File "__main__.py", line 331, in bootstrap
File "__main__.py", line 358, in chainload
File "__main__.py", line 834, in _chainload
File "my_code.py", line 49, in <module>
File "esky\__init__.pyc", line 471, in cleanup
File "esky\__init__.pyc", line 516, in _cleanup_actions
File "esky\__init__.pyc", line 465, in cleanup
File "esky\__init__.pyc", line 882, in install_version
File "esky\__init__.pyc", line 914, in _unpack_bootstrap_env
File "esky\fstransact\win32txf.pyc", line 109, in move
File "esky\fstransact\win32txf.pyc", line 118, in _move
File "esky\fstransact\win32txf.pyc", line 24, in wrapper
WindowsError: [Error 6805] The remote server or share does not support transacted file operations.
```

On the server I see that the update is requested twice.

```
weapon101s.ds.com - - [23/May/2013 10:47:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
weapon101s.ds.com - - [23/May/2013 10:47:26] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
weapon101s.ds.com - - [23/May/2013 10:47:26] "GET /hifg-1.1.1.win32.zip HTTP/1.1" 200 -
weapon101s.ds.susq.com - - [23/May/2013 10:48:08] "GET /hifg-1.1.1.win32.zip HTTP/1.1" 200 -
weapon101s.ds.susq.com - - [23/May/2013 10:49:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
weapon101s.ds.susq.com - - [23/May/2013 10:49:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

this is probably a network issue since the problem does not occur on the local network but only when update from a remote site. Any ideas on whats wrong and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esky is using transactional NTFS to maintain data integrity when moving files, specifically the [MoveFileTransacted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. However, transactional NTFS only works on local files.

Quoting the Microsoft docs, [When to Use Transactional NTFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365738%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> TxF does not support the following transaction scenarios:
>
> - Transactions on network volumes, for example on file shares. TxF is not supported by the CIFS/SMB protocols.
> - Transactions on any file system other than NTFS.
> - Transacted operations against files cached by client-side caching.
> - File access using object IDs.
> - Any shared writer scenario.
> - Any situation where a file is opened for an extended period of time (days or weeks).

I'm not sure there is any way of solving this other than not updating remotely.